# AutoCAD ARX function to get closed area around selected point

Tags: autocad-plugin, objectarx

Deep in the abyss of my memory there is info that in AutoCAD API ObjectARX , there is function to get closed area arround known point but I don't remember name of this function. It works something simmilar to command _boundary, but not command which can be run by User interface, but clead ARX function .
Can anybody remember name of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ObjectARX/C++, it is `acedTraceBoundary`

In .NET, it is `Editor.TraceBoundary`